# Show Jquery dialog in previous page

Tags: php, jquery

This is my registration form located in login.html:

```
<form action="Registar.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username (Sem espaços)"  maxlength="25">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" maxlength="31"/>
    <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" maxlength="31"/>
    <input type="text" name="morada" placeholder="Morada" maxlength="120"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
    <input type="number" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="15"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Signup</button> 
</form>
```

It goes to "Registar.php" and runs the verification's i want like if the fields are empty or if the username already exists and show's that verification's in a jquery dialog.
Heres my Jquery script:

```
function alerta(msg,link){
  var dialog = $('<div>'+msg+'</div>');
  $(function() {
    $( dialog ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {  
          window.location = link;
        }
      }
    });
  })
};
```

The thing is it shows the dialog on the blank page of "Registar.php" and since i scripted some nice styles and overlays for my jquery dialog i want to show the jquery dialog verification messages in login.html and have that page in the background/overlay of the dialog.

Is there any way to do that but still running the action form to an external php script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one way to do this would be to use an AJAX call instead of a form submitted via POST.  AJAX would call register.php and get a response, and then show the dialog.

Comment: Hmm interesting, can u give me and example or a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use AJAX instead of sending the form via POST.  Here's an example:

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
  //your form content
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop form submission
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Registar.php",
       data: formData,
       success: function(result) {
           //result is the value returned from Registrar.php
           console.log(result);
           //show the modal
       }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7q15qth/2/)

Comment: Yes i have already tried this before but since the jquery call is in the php file it doesn't show the dialog.
I've made some tests and it shows everything i want excepts the jquery dialog modal :/.

Comment: It could be a type of return values problem ? Since it returns a jquery and not really php because my return of my verifications and i said above appear in a jquery dialog.

Comment: the JQuery I posted above should go in the same file as your HTML form.  your Register.php should receive the posted values from ajax and return some value (perhaps true or false) which then can be used to display the modal back on the page with the form.

Comment: yes it receives but it doesn't show the modal, above the success i have:
$("#result").html(result);

Comment: you will need to add code to show the modal.  such as $('#myModalDivId').show();

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle link to my answer.  I mocked up the ajax response and have shown how to display it in an alert.  You can use the same concept for your modal.

Comment: But inside the php i call the jquery modal a lot of times to show the verifications. if i put the modal ID it just shows me one.

Comment: I don't have your complete code so I can't say for sure.  You should have a modal template, add the current message to the template, display it, and then clear the message from the template once the modal is closed.  That way, you can re-use the same modal with various messages.

Comment: My php file only returns the echo of modal messages, that's the thing. if it shows normal echos, why can't show the echo of my dialog?

Comment: I think your php file should return a string.  The modal should reside in the file with Javascript / JQuery and HTML.

Comment: and then i call the php string in the modal? That might work, i just dont know how to call the strings in the modal

Comment: AJAX calls your php page.  your php page returns the message string to the AJAX call.  you put that response string in your modal.

Comment: That might work, can u just give an example of how can i store the string i receive and then put it in the modal. I really appreciate your time and help with this

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle linked in my answer to show how to take the response from Ajax and append it to a modal.  https://jsfiddle.net/b7q15qth/2/

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, ill try it when i come back from work :)